# CNN (VGG-16) outputs only one class in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've been training CNN model for stock price prediction (whether the price's going to increase or stay, which is binary classification problem) using its 20-days chart image data. Although I have changed hyperparameters such as lr (from 1e-1 to 1e-15), weight_decay, batch_size, image_size, and etc and applied lr_scheduler, the **model's accuracy stays along with the ratio of dominant class of validation dataset**. Which means, if the validation dataset has 60% of lable 0, then the accuracy stays around ~60%. This happens all the times as I change the ratio of the validation dataset.

There are **30000** images total, and I am using **24000 as train**, **3000 as validation** (another 3000 for test).

The input of the model is image of stock chart data (size of 64 * 64 * 3).

[Click to see sample input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFRTw.jpg)

The structure of the VGG-16 model is added below.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class VGG16(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_size: int, num_classes: int):
        super(VGG16, self).__init__()
        self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv1_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv2_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv3_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv4_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.conv5_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv5_2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv5_3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        if img_size == 50:
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 4096)
        else:
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(int(img_size * img_size / 2), 4096)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 4096)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4096, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv1_2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2_2(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3_2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3_3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4_3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv5_3(x))
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.5)  # dropout was included to combat over fitting
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.5)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        # x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

Code for Training Step:

```
        for epoch in range(self.config.num_epoch):
            self.model.train()
            train_losses = []
            for batch in tqdm(self.train_loader, desc=f"Epoch[{epoch}] Train Step: "):
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss = self._train_batch(batch)
                train_losses.append(loss)
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()

            self.lr_scheduler.step()
```

```
    def _train_batch(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch
        images = images.to(self.device)
        labels = labels.to(self.device)
        out = self.model(images)  # Generate predictions
        loss = self.criterion(out, labels)  # Calculate loss
        return loss
```

Training logs (50:50 for label 0 and 1):

```
Epoch 1 Train: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 62/62 [00:06<00:00,  9.04it/s]
Epoch 1 Evaluate: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7/7 [00:00<00:00, 12.67it/s]
2022-06-09 19:41:33,054Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _train() : Epoch[1]: train_loss: 5.4477, valid_loss: 2.1717, valid_acc: 0.5084, lr: 0.0996
2022-06-09 19:41:33,403Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _save_model() : Successfully saved model
Epoch 2 Train: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 62/62 [00:06<00:00,  9.04it/s]
Epoch 2 Evaluate: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7/7 [00:00<00:00, 12.49it/s]
2022-06-09 19:41:40,930Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _train() : Epoch[2]: train_loss: 2.3148, valid_loss: 1.8339, valid_acc: 0.5078, lr: 0.0994
2022-06-09 19:41:41,279Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _save_model() : Successfully saved model
Epoch 3 Train: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 62/62 [00:06<00:00,  9.04it/s]
Epoch 3 Evaluate: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7/7 [00:00<00:00, 12.70it/s]
2022-06-09 19:41:48,790Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _train() : Epoch[3]: train_loss: 1.8587, valid_loss: 1.4972, valid_acc: 0.4961, lr: 0.0992
2022-06-09 19:41:49,136Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _save_model() : Successfully saved model
Epoch 4 Train: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 62/62 [00:06<00:00,  9.02it/s]
Epoch 4 Evaluate: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7/7 [00:00<00:00, 11.53it/s]
2022-06-09 19:41:56,719Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _train() : Epoch[4]: train_loss: 1.6496, valid_loss: 1.4223, valid_acc: 0.4972, lr: 0.0990
2022-06-09 19:41:57,068Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _save_model() : Successfully saved model
Epoch 5 Train: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 62/62 [00:06<00:00,  9.04it/s]
Epoch 5 Evaluate: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 7/7 [00:00<00:00, 12.71it/s]
2022-06-09 19:42:04,585Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _train() : Epoch[5]: train_loss: 1.3693, valid_loss: 0.9528, valid_acc: 0.4972, lr: 0.0988
2022-06-09 19:42:04,950Z | src.stock_prediction.service.trainer | INFO  | _save_model() : Successfully saved model
```

Optimizer I am using is Adam, and criterion is CrossEntropyLoss. I've been stuck on this problem for long time, and I really couldn't figure it out. Please let me know if you know what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the task is just too hard for the CNN so it resorts to outputting always the most common class? A RNN with the numbers instead of the image as inputs would be a better architecture

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I recognize that the problem is too complicated, the previous study has been published [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.12258.pdf) , and I am trying to implement this using PyTorch instead of TensorFlow which the author of the paper has been used. You can refer to this [github](https://github.com/riron1206/candlestick_model) for the code of this paper.

Comment: Also, I want to ask there's no siginificant issue you can find from my code?

Comment: I cannot say as I did not study it in detail

Comment: What is your input data format exactly?

Comment: It's image of 20 days stock chart data with size of 64 * 64 and 3 channels in RGB. You can see the sample image from the post. The data type of the input image is PIL.Image.Image, and this is being converted to torch.tensor of shape (3, 64, 64) by using torchvision.transforms.ToTensor() before its called from the dataloader